# VS Code - File Explorer / Explorer change case

Tags: visual-studio-code

Sorry if the question is bit silly, but on Ubuntu 16.4 I am trying out code editors for Angular 2. VS Code appeals because of TypeScript. But when I open a location the directory name in File Explorer is in ALL CAPS even though I don't use CAPS in directory names? Googling didn't help. Perhaps I am missing something.

How can I change it show my directory name **exactly** as it is in Ubuntu please? I have tried to look into settings.json etc but no joy.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

if you mean this (see the image below), that would be a standard behaviour and has nothing to do with actual size of the letters. As far as I can tell, you cannot change this.

[image: Screenshot of the explorer menu in VSCode]

Comment: Hmm I figured as much, that sucks. Okay thanks, I'll wait till there is any solution to this. Perhaps I can download repo and do something with source and then build locally? I'll see. Thanks anyway.

Comment: You can try to make an extension if you like. You can create an issue and they will at least tell you if it is possible.

Comment: Fair enough, done. [VS Code Link](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/26718).

Answer (score 0):

Well I went to GitHub as suggested but they have sadly [declined (click)](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/26718) to do anything about this as some "as designed" thing, whatever that means. Pretty bad, but okay whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to customise. https://gist.github.com/Hendrixer/7a250a2be529cda8939de8305c9a85a1

It's just another chromium based renderer. Open developer console and customise anything you like.